# Updating a LinkedList

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jcombobox

My case is very specific here:

First, I have an already-defined array of Strings that contains the default options (which are always the same for all users) of a JComboBox:

```
private static final String[]   JOB_TYPE = {options go here};
```

These options are loaded into the JComboBox as follows:

```
private JComboBox   jobType = new JComboBox(JOB_TYPE);
```

Then, there are other options that can vary from one user to another that I have to load inside the JComboBox as well. Since arrays have a fixed number of elements, I had to find another way to add the specific options besides the default ones into the JComboBox. And so what I did was, I created a LinkedList and used the asList method from Arrays to load the default options of the array inside it, then add the other options which vary from one user to another:

```
private List<String> allJobs = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(JOB_TYPE));
```

allJobs can now be passed on as an argument for the JCombobox using the toArray() method:

```
private JComboBox   jobType = new JComboBox(allJobs.toArray());
```

Now, I have all the default options in allJobs, and since it's no longer an array, I can also add to it the specific options which will be loaded as follows:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < modelJobCustomType.getSize(); j++) {
        allJobs.add(((XmlJobCustomElem) modelJobCustomType.getElementAt(j)).getName());
    }
```

Now, here's my problem:

When I check the content of the JComboBox, I only find the default options, and not the specific ones even though I can see using the debugger that the list size has increased and it contains the specific options as well.

My guess is, since jobType, JOB_TYPE and allJobs are global variables, the ComboBox is being populated way before the compiler gets to the part of the code where it loads the specific options as well, and that's probably why I can only see the default options.

Is this correct? And if so, how can I fix this problem. Keep in mind that those global variables have to stay global because they are also being used in many other parts of the class.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Sounds like you are right.  Can you delay instantiating `jobType` until after you have initialized allJobs?  Or, can you use the JComboBox API to update its contents (`addItem(...)`, `removeItem(...)`, etc...)

Comment: I didn't even know about addItem() method. Thank you so much, that's exactly what I had to do.

Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The combobox is given the array derived from a list. Afterwards adding to the list will not change the array value (arrays are fixed length values),

There also is a `JComboBox` with a `Vector` parameter, that allows adding (as opposed to an array).

However the nicest is a `JComboBox` with a `ComboBoxModel<E>` parameter that is the most high-level. There is a default implementation [`DefaultComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html):

```
DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(JOB_TYPE);
model.addElement("custom0");
model.addElement("custom1");
combobox = new JComboBox(model);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize your class like this to let you keep all the jobs in `allJobs` at initialization rather than the custom ones only existing in the `JComboBox` as in Jamie's solution. You could also do all the initializing of the instance fields inside the constructors:

```
class Main {
    private static final List<String> FIXED_OPTIONS = Arrays.asList("fixed0", "fixed1", "fixed2");

    private List<String> allJobs = new ArrayList<>(FIXED_OPTIONS);
    {
        int count = 6;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            allJobs.add("custom" + i);
        }
    }

    private JComboBox jobType = new JComboBox(allJobs.toArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your answer works with many different scenarios, but not with mine unfortunately. Upon initialization, the compiler will throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` because `modelJobCustomType` which is a `MapListComboModel` still has no elements and has a zero size. So  when I try to load the custom jobs like this:   `allJobs.add(((XmlJobCustomElem) modelJobCustomType.getElementAt(j)).getName());`, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the source: JComboBox

```
181:   /**
182:    * Constructs JComboBox with specified list of items.
183:    *
184:    * @param itemArray array containing list of items for this JComboBox
185:    */
186:   public JComboBox(Object[] itemArray)
187:   {
188:     this(new DefaultComboBoxModel(itemArray));
189:     
190:     if (itemArray.length > 0) 
191:       setSelectedIndex(0);
192:   }
```

The constructor creates a new instance of the DefaultComboBoxModel.